# Structure of subgroups of $A = \{ m2^n \mid m,n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, examples-counterexamples, rational-numbers

Let $A = \{ m2^n \mid m,n\in \mathbb{Z} \} \le (\mathbb{Q}, +)$. I am looking to find how subgroups $H\le A$ work. My suspect is that they have some kind of "boundedness" condition on the denominator. I'll explain in more detail what I mean.

Given $H < A$ proper, does there exist a $d\in \mathbb{Z}$ such that $\forall m2^n \in H$ we have $d\le n$?

---

What I have noted is that there exist obvious subgroups that are of the form
$$H_i = \{ m2^i \mid m\in \mathbb{Z} \} \cong 2^i\mathbb{Z}$$
with $H_i \subset H_{i-1}$ for all $i\in \mathbb{Z}$. These subgroups look like they might be the only ones of $A$, in which case we would have a positive answer. If you have counterexamples or some insight, it would be greatly appreciated.

---

UPDATE: As suggested in the comments of an answer, a generalization of the possible subgroups would be $m2^n \mathbb{Z}$ with $m,n\in \mathbb{Z}$.

Comment: Check the comments of [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488952/the-proper-subgroups-of-a-left-lbrace-m-pn-m-in-mathbbz-n-geq-0-right).

Comment: $A$ itself is a subgroup of $A$ without that "boundedness" property;  but your question still stands for proper subgroups.

Comment: Yes, thanks for the observation. I will edit it since I meant proper, as you said

Answer (score 3):

That is wrong.

The group $3\mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $A$.

Edit: To answer the updated question

My proof to [The proper subgroups of $A:=\left\lbrace m/p^n : m\in \mathbb{Z}; n \geq 0 \right\rbrace$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488952/the-proper-subgroups-of-a-left-lbrace-m-pn-m-in-mathbbz-n-geq-0-righ?noredirect=1&lq=1) implies that if $H$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$, then it takes the form $2^{-i}\mathbb{Z}$ for some $i\geq 0$ (or $H=A$).

Now take $H$ an arbitrary subgroup. Then $H\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ and so isomorphic to $2^{-i}\mathbb{Z}$, or to $A$ which we will now informally denote by $2^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$.

$H\cap \mathbb{Z}$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}$ and therefore isomorphic to some $m\mathbb{Z}$ where $m\in\mathbb{N}$.

We now prove that $H=m2^{-i}\mathbb{Z}$, where $i$ is potentially infinity.

To see that $H\subseteq m2^{-i}\mathbb{Z}$, let $h\in H$. The obvious inclusion $H\subseteq H\oplus \mathbb{Z}$ implies that $h\in 2^{-i}\mathbb{Z}$, write $h=\frac{n}{2^i}$ for some $n$ coprime to $2$ (if $i$ is infinity then, write $h=\frac{n}{2^l}$ for any $l$). Indeed, since $h\in H$, we also have that $n\in H$, since $H\cap \mathbb{Z} = m\mathbb{Z}$ we deduce that $n$ is a multiple of $m$. Hence, $h\in m\cdot 2^{-i}\mathbb{Z}$.

Now we prove the other direction. Let $x\in m\cdot 2^{-i}\mathbb{Z}$, we need to prove that $x\in H$. Now write $x = m\cdot t$ where $t\in 2^{-i}\mathbb{Z} = H\oplus \mathbb{Z}$. We can therefore find some $h\in H$ and $z\in \mathbb{Z}$ so that $t=h+z$. Hence, $x=mh + mz$. Clearly $mh\in H$ and since $z\in\mathbb{Z}$ and $H\cap\mathbb{Z} = m\mathbb{Z}$ we deduce that $mz\in H$. Hence, $x\in H$ and the claim follows.

Comment: So it is wrong that all proper subroups are of the form $2^i\mathbb{Z}$ with $i \in \mathbb{Z}$, but it could be still true that they are all respect that "boundedness" condition? Maybe one could generalize saying that all proper subgroups are of the form $2^i\mathbb{Z}$ $i \in \mathbb{Z}$ or of the form $m\mathbb{Z}$ ($m \in \mathbb{Z}$).

Comment: I think the correct thing would be $m\cdot 2^i\mathbb{Z}$ (it is important that you can divide by $2$ sometimes)

Comment: @Measureme If you assume that $V$ contains $\mathbb{Z}$ then the only subgroups are of the form $2^i\mathbb{Z}$ with $i\leq 0$. I prove that in here just now https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4488952/the-proper-subgroups-of-a-left-lbrace-m-pn-m-in-mathbbz-n-geq-0-righ?noredirect=1&lq=1

Comment: If you follow the argument with $H$ contains $m\mathbb{Z}$ instead, it will still work, I think, but will be more technically complicated. (sorry in the last comment I wrote $V$ for $H$)

Comment: That's a better way to put it, thanks. I'll add it to the question as an update. Anyways the assumprion of having $\mathbb{Z}$ isn't an assumption I really want, because I am looking at all possible proper subgroups.

Comment: @Measureme You need to make an extra update, as it could also be equal to $m\cdot A$ which informally we can write as "$m\cdot 2^{-\infty}\mathbb{Z}$" and formally as the union of $m\cdot 2^{-n}\mathbb{Z}$ over $n$.

Comment: @Measureme I edit my question including the more general statement that you needed.

Comment: Yeah, I was thinking of an example which I think is somewhat similar to yours: $H_m = \{ mk2^n \mid k,n\in \mathbb{Z} \}$ which is a proper subgroup and doesn't respect that "boundedness" condition...

Comment: That counterexample also probaly needs the assumption that $m$ is odd.

Comment: @Measureme Well not necessarily, because you can take $m=6$. Only when $m$ is a power of $2$ you get one of the previous examples.

Comment: I think $H_6$ would be $H_3$, in fact take an element $6k2^n\in H_6$ which is also $3k2^{n+1}\in H_3$; the converse also works. I also think this generalizes to any number  .